# How to align a print() in python

Tags: python

```
import getpass
from art import *
tprint("Hangman")
print("The game is for 2 players")
def guess():
    guess_word = getpass.getpass("What is the word you want guess to him? ")
    chara = print("The choosen word has:\n",len(guess_word),"characters")
    characters = list(guess_word)
    return characters
characters = guess()
for a in characters:
    bjr = print("_")
```

when my variable `"bjr = print("hello")"` the Em dash is like that

how to align "_" like that :

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to *print* or to make a variable full of underscores? Because `bjr = print("_")` prints, then assigns the return value of `print` (`None`) to `bjr`, which makes `bjr` fairly useless. You can print or you can assign, trying to do both at once is a bad idea (it's technically possible in modern Python, but not the way you're doing it, and I'm hesitant to introduce you to it, as it's bad style.).

Answer (score 0):

Change the last print to print without wrapping
Add `end=''` inside the `print()`.

```
bjr = print("_", end = '')
```

In your case:

```
import getpass
from art import *
tprint("Hangman")
print("The game is for 2 players")
def guess():
    guess_word = getpass.getpass("What is the word you want guess to him? ")
    chara = print("The choosen word has:\n",len(guess_word),"characters")
    characters = list(guess_word)
    return characters
characters = guess()
for a in characters:
    bjr = print("_", end = '')
```

You can change de `''` in `end=` with the font of your choice.
The standard one for wrapping is `\n`
which is the one used implicitly when you use `print("_")`